# Using wide strings with ifstream::open or multibyte strings with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, string

I have a piece of code in which I need to use a string with both ifstream::open and CreateProcess, something like

```
//in another file
const char* FILENAME = "C:\\...blah blah\\filename.bat";
```

---

```
// in main app
std::ifstream is;
is.open(FILENAME);
// ...do some writing
is.close();

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

std::string cmdLine = "/c " + FILENAME;

if( !CreateProcess( "c:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", 
    cmdLine.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) ) 
{       
    return GetLastError();
}
```

CreateProcess requires a LPCWSTR, so to use the string with CreateProcess I would need to declare the filename and 'cmdLine' as std::wstring, but ifstream::open doesn't take wide strings...I can't figure a way to get around this. I always seem to run into problems with unicode vs multibyte strings.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use e.g. [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) to convert from `char *` to `wchar_t *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you defined `UNICODE`. You can change `STARTUPINFO` to `STARTUPINFOA` and `CreateProcess` to `CreateProcessA` and it should work fine (it did for me).

I don't think it'll like the + operation though. Explicitly convert one char array to a string.

```
std::string cmdLine = (std::string)"/c " + FILENAME;
```

Finally, you're going to need quotes around the beginning and end of `FILENAME` if it has a space.

```
const char FILENAME = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Program\\program.exe\"";
                        ^           ^                                     ^
```

Edit:
Try putting this below your string declaration:

```
char charCmdLine [MAX_PATH + 3]; //"/c " is 3 extra chars
strncpy (charCmdLine, cmdLine.c_str(), MAX_PATH + 3);
```

Then, use `charCmdLine` in `CreateProcess` instead of `cmdLine.c_str()`.

Comment: Yes unicode is defined, OK now I get the error:

CreateProcessA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPSTR'

EDIT - I'm not sure how to edit this properly but the italic words are where I've written an asterisk, they should be pointers

but LPSTR is just char* right? =S

Comment: const char * is LPCSTR, which is what `c_str()` returns. You might have to copy it into a new buffer then, but it's surprising it didn't give me a warning or anything then. edit: never mind, it did give me a warning >.<

Comment: It's because of the difference in constness, it expects a LPSTR not LPCSTR, can I get around this without const_cast?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It now compiles without warning (yes, I'm sure this time!)